# Amazon Athena convert string to date time

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a string in the following format `dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm`, eg `23-Oct-2020 20:23`, which I wish to convert to a datetime. I've tried:

```
parse_datetime(string, '%D-%M-%Y %H:%M')
```

but I'm hitting am error:

> 'INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format. Can anyone lend a helping hand please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse_datetime` uses Java datetime formats. You can try:

```sql
select parse_datetime('23-Oct-2020 20:23', 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm')
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 2020-10-23 20:23:00.000 UTC |

Or use MySQL format with [`date_parse`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions):

```sql
select date_parse('23-Oct-2020 20:24', '%d-%b-%Y %H:%i')
```

Comment: Great, the first option worked. Thanks. Now converted, would I be able to add 30 minutes to the datetime?

Comment: @Coopernicus yes, you would. Check the [presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) docs. `+ interval '30' minutes` or something like this.